# Create Unordered List from View Query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query that will produce the results I need:

```
SELECT SHOW_NAME, YEAR, CLASS_NAME FROM vwhandlerresults WHERE HANDLER_ID = $gethandlerid ORDER BY YEAR DESC

SHOW_NAME    YEAR    CLASS_NAME
Show 1       2013    Class 1
Show 1       2013    Class 2
Show 2       2013    Class 1
Show 3       2012    Class 1
```

etc. etc.

I want to create a 3 level unordered list in php so that I can have something similar to the following:

```
2013
     Show 1
          Class 1
          Class 2
     Show 2
          Class 1
2012
     Show 3
          Class 1
```

I have searched and searched, and can't get my head around it at all. I managed it to one level (Year -> Show). From searching, I get the feeling I might need an array?

Thanks

Gray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you don't need to build an array in advance. You can do it as the data is fetched from the DB using a simple-ish "state machine".

```
echo '<ul>';
$oldyear = null;
$oldshow = null;
while($row = fetch_result($result)) { // grab a row of DB data
   if ($oldyear != $row['year']) {
      echo "<li>{$row['year']}<ul>";
   }
   if ($oldshow != $row['show']) {
     echo "<li>{$row['show']}<ul>";
   }
   echo "<li>{$row['class']}</li>";
}
```

NOTE: this will NOT work as is, it's just to give you a general idea of what'd be needed if you choose to go this route

However, if you choose to go with the array route, it'll be a bit more work upfront, but vastly simplify the output logic:

```
$data = array();
while($row = fetch_row($result)) {
   $year = $row['year'];
   $show = $row['show'];
   $data[$year][$show][] = $row['class'];
}

echo '<ul>'
foreach($years as $year => $shows) {
   echo '<li>', $year, '<ul>';
   foreach($shows as $show) {
      echo '<li>$show<ul>';
      foreach ($show as $class) {
          echo '<li>', $class, '</li>';
      }
      echo '</ul>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Seems array may be the way to do – assuming $result is the result of the query?

Comment: yep. whatever you get back from the query to fetch from.

Comment: where is $class defined in the array? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: sorry, missed that in the fetch-from-db loop.

Comment: Cheers Marc - I'll go and see if I can get my head around it